# Change Twitter Tweet Button Text

Tags: javascript, twitter

I've looked around but can't seem to find a way to do this. Below is my Twitter tweet button code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{$post-      >permalink}" data-text="{$themeOptions->directory->shareText} {$post->permalink}" data-lang="en" style="background:#000000;">WANT NEW TEXT HERE</a>
```

Regardless of what I enter for the link text, like above, it always changes to Tweet. I'm assuming this is the Twitter JS script. Is there a way around this?

Comment: maybe you can try changing the text after the DOM has been loaded in a `window.onload` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's all you need to know, if you mean creating your own TWEET button the example uses JQuery.. http://www.ejhansel.com/create-a-custom-twitter-tweet-button/

Or is your question about personalizing the existing generic Tweet button?

Comment: In a perfect world, I'd personalize the existing generic Tweet button

Comment: I don't believe Twitter allow the personalization of the Tweet button. With the exception of the generated text of the tweet.